# Chrome does not follow hosts file

Tags: linux, google-chrome, hosts-file

I have custom domains set up for internal web site testing in my `/etc/hosts` file.

I try to access them in Chrome, and I get routed to a Google search instead.  But when I ping the domains, they show that they are working.

What should I do to make sure I can access these sites in Chrome?

Comment: Chrome dev team says they [WontFix](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26545) this.  The extension [Host Switch Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/host-switch-plus/bopepoejgapmihklfepohbilpkcdoaeo) does not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Disable "Use a web service to help resolve navigation errors" in Chrome's Settings under Privacy. Try flushing Chrome's cache after disabling this and see if it works then.

Comment: This is a less-optimal way of solving it. Without http:// in front of the domain, Chrome may assume that you've made a "navigation error" / lazy search. With http:// it shouldn't argue.

Answer (score 4):

You can just throw an `http://` in front of your local address; that worked for me.

Comment: This should do it. By declaring the http:// protocol up front Chrome should assume you know what you're doing and just try the address as given instead of trying to be helpful.

Comment: Doesn't worked for me. The Chome just writes «Couldn't retrieve URL», although plain ping there works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

As the answer in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841421/mac-osx-lion-dns-lookup-order), the solution for me was adding `::1` in `/etc/hosts` like:

```
127.0.0.1 foo.domain.local
::1 foo.domain.local
```

Comment: This really shouldn't affect the situation unless you're trying to override the domain name of a real site that happens to be IPv6 enabled and point it back to your local machine.

Answer (score 2):

just use the domains like so http://localstite.dev/ .

It's the "/" at the end to resolve the host...

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/hosts` list them like this:

```
192.168.0.4 foo.localdomain
```

Now when you type `foo.domain` in the address bar it will still return search results but you should see a bar asking you if you meant to go to `foo.localdomain` instead.

Strangely once I had got Chrome to do this once it started doing it for single host names in `/etc/hosts` but I had to use the `host.domain` form first.

Comment: I don't even get that bar.  It's a fully-qualified domain name too.